# Stephan Boltzmann law

Tags: luminosity

I was preparing for INAO when I came across the application of Stephan Boltzmann law...it's says that energy absorbed per unit time by a planet is Flux times πr^2. But why did we multiply with πr^2 or how did we replace a sphere with a disk? (where r is radius of planet and flux is received flux...)

Comment: I don't think a sphere was replaced by a disk. I think you might want to consider that $\pi r^2$ as something else.

Comment: that is the area perpendicular to the flux that is absorbing the flux